# When deploying contract using hardhat to Mumbai (Polygon) the address already exists

Tags: polygon, solidity, hardhat

Contract deploys to address [0x47c5e40890bcE4a473A49D7501808b9633F29782](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x47c5e40890bcE4a473A49D7501808b9633F29782)

It looks like many other contracts were deployed to the same address by other people.

Should the address of the contract not be unique or is it deterministically generated or cached somehow by hardhat?

Why would other people have deployed to the same address?
I am wondering if this is some bug with Polygon/Mumbai testnet

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const SuperMarioWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("Rilu");
  const superMarioWorld = await SuperMarioWorld.deploy("Rilu", "RILU");
  await superMarioWorld.deployed();
  console.log("Success contract was deployed to: ", superMarioWorld.address)

  await superMarioWorld.mint("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZkUCDt5CVRWQjLDyRS4c8kU6UxRNdpsjMf6vomDcd7ep")
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Hardhat

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.4',
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: process.env.MUMBAI_RPC,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```

.env file (no problem with sharing the private key, just one I got from vanity-eth.tk and used for testing)

```
PRIVATE_KEY=84874e85685c95440e51d5edacf767f952f596cca6fd3da19b90035a20f57e37
MUMBAI_RPC=https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com
```

Output

```
~/g/s/b/r/nft ❯❯❯ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai   ✘ 1 
Compiling 12 files with 0.8.4
Compilation finished successfully
Success contract was deployed to:  0x47c5e40890bcE4a473A49D7501808b9633F29782
```

Comment: The provided private key generates the `0x47c5...` address, which doesn't hold any contract bytecode (on the Mumbai testnet). So the issue is somewhere in assigning the `superMarioWorld.address` value in the JS code... Btw, it's not possible to deploy multiple contract instances to the same address  - just one at most (at the same time; there's an edge case allowing to selfdestruct a contract and then re-deploy it to the same address).

Comment: I replaced the mumbai network with rinkeby and everything works well with no other changes. The reason you probably don't see anything at the address I pasted is because someone deployed a contract to that address before me. This is the address on Rinkeby that works https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0xde41cd6a2c32efc1f467a3831839fa59c56ad296/1